# Differential equation in Potential of circular symmetry "D

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Given the potential $U_{pot} = \frac 1 2 k r^2$ where $\vec r = (x,y)$, $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ we can calculate the force

$$\vec F = - \nabla U_{pot} = -2k \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}2(x,y) =  -2k \frac 1 r \vec r \qquad\qquad (1)$$

Is this correct?

Now with Newton, we can construct the differential equation

$$ m \ddot{\vec r} = m \vec a \overset{!}{=} F = -2 k \frac 1 r \vec r \qquad\qquad (2)$$ Is this correct so far?

Alternatively with coordinates:

$$\begin{pmatrix} \ddot{x} \\ \ddot{y} \end{pmatrix} = -2 \frac k m \frac 1  {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix} \qquad \qquad(3)$$

Now my question is, how can I solve this system of differential equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes. Note that 
$$ {\def\p{\text{pot}}}U_\p(x,y) = \frac 12 k(x^2 + y^2)  $$
Hence 
$$ \partial_x U_\p(x,y) = kx,\qquad \partial_y U_\p(x,y) = ky $$
there fore 
$$ F(x,y) = -\nabla U_\p(x,y) = -k\vec r $$
Your ode reads
$$ m\ddot{\vec r} = -k\vec r $$

Comment: Thank you very much, I suspected I must have made such a stupid mistake for I got so strange results=)

Answer (score 1):

There should be no 1/r part.  It will just be
$$\ddot{x}=-\frac{k}{m}x$$
$$\ddot{y}=-\frac{k}{m}y$$
so two decoupled harmonic oscillators.